# A-t-on d'autres équivalents que « jongler » pour traduire le « balancing/juggling act » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions, substantivation

[*Larousse*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/balancing/564302) (en ligne anglais-français) traduit l'adjectif/nom composé au figuré « balancing act » avec le verbe *jongler* dans le contexte suivant :

> *It was a real balancing act keeping everyone happy* (figurative)
> il fallait **jongler** pour pouvoir satisfaire tout le monde.

Ça connote l'idée de « résoudre en se jouant » ([Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0260)) et c'est certainement utile, a fortiori comme on peut aussi parler d'un « [juggling act](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/act) » (tBD) mais on ne pourra pas utiliser [*jonglerie*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0261) il me semble dans des contextes de phrases où un nom pourrait mieux convenir, entre autres parce qu'autrement on pourrait devoir reformuler complètement :

> *It's a difficult balancing act, but many students hold full-time jobs
> while attending school.
>
> Working and raising children can be a real juggling act for parents.*

---

- Quel pourrait être ce nom ?
- Peut-on traduire l'un ou l'autre de ces derniers exemples avec
  *jongler* et comparer si l'on trouve ça plus naturel qu'avec le terme identifié précédemment et indiquer pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3):

Pour ma part, je pense à l'expression **jouer un numéro d'équilibriste**, qui garde l'aspect "acrobatie", mais sans le côté "jonglerie".

- c'est un **numéro d'équilibriste** de travailler à plein temps tout en élevant des enfants/ en faisant des études supérieures.

autre exemple :

> **Le numéro d'équilibriste des Républicains**
>
> Le projet de loi sur les retraites met à l'épreuve la droite, tiraillée entre une réforme qu'elle appelait de ses vœux dans son programme et la crainte de laisser échapper d'autres électeurs vers le Rassemblement national.

D'autre part, linguee semble traduire cette expression par *balacing act* la plupart du temps : https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/num%C3%A9ro+d%27%C3%A9quilibriste.html

> Une communication efficace sur le lieu de travail peut
> ressembler à un numéro d'équilibriste.
>
> Effective communication in
> the workplace can be a balancing act

Answer (score 0):

Ça m'inspire *louvoyer*, *manier l'art du compromis* et *faire preuve de diplomatie* mais sans exactement correspondre au sens ou à l'unicité attendus.